# how find difference in customer address in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am trying to validate the duplication of the customer address using mysql.

Customer 1:
58 Avenue Rd, London, NW10 4UU

Customer 2: 
58 Avenue Road, London, NW10 4UU -

How to find the duplicate customer address? Both are same. 
But "Customer 2" adds some "-" in the same address. 
But we cant accept this address. Because both are same.

I am using this query.

```
SELECT COUNT(customer_address) FROM customer WHERE customer_address = '$customer_address'
```

But it returns 0. so it accepts customer 2. This is wrong.

I am trying another way.

```
SELECT COUNT(customer_address) FROM customer WHERE customer_address LIKE '%".$customer_address."%'
```

But it gives wrong result.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following;

```
SELECT
    c.customer_address
FROM
    customer c
WHERE
    c.customer_address IN (
        SELECT
            customer_address
        FROM
            customer
        HAVING
            COUNT(DISTINCT customer_address) > 1
    )
```

#### For example, with this data;

```
+---------------------------------------+
| customer_address                      |
+---------------------------------------+
| 58 Avenue Road, London, NW10 4UU      |
| 58 Avenue Road, London, NW10 4UU -    |
| 16 Beach Road, Bournemouth, NA66 6NA  |
+---------------------------------------+
```

**I get**

```
+-------------------------------------+
| customer_address                    |
+-------------------------------------+
| 58 Avenue Road, London, NW10 4UU -  |
+-------------------------------------+
1 row in set
```

As there is a row returned, we know this is a duplicate address.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are eager to learn finding it by yourself, I give you a good start on google: you would want to search for "mysql edit distance"...